# Having trouble writing to a file with PHP on Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, file-io, file-permissions

I am running PHP 5.5.9 on Ubuntu 14.04. I'm having trouble writing to a file. I feel like this has to be a file permissions problem because I'm pretty sure the code is correct. The user that I'm logged in as has permissions to write in the folders that I am trying to write into, but I'm not sure if the localhost does. I'm not sure what the name of the localhost user is in order to use `chmod`. I tried using `chmod 777 -R /var/www/html` and the script is still is not able to write to my target folder, which has the path `/var/www/html/Projects/MD_ScrapingTool/files`. Here is my code:

```
$file = 'filetest.txt';
if($handle = fopen($file, 'w')) {
    $content = "123\n456";
    fwrite($handle, $content);
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "Could not open file for writing.";
}
```

Comment: With `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of your PHP file, what errors are being output?

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Do you see your echo statement? If so, that means you cannot open a file handle, which is a possible indication that the path you are specifying to the file is not correct. You might try using the absolute path to the file. You can use is_file and is_writable to help you debug as well. Also, you might consider using file_put_contents instead of working with fopen,fwrite and fclose.

Comment: If you solve your problem by yourself you should post it as an answer. Please don't edit the *question* to add an answer though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After some more research, I've got it figured out. Here is the solution for anyone having the same problem:
Since localhost belongs to the `www-data` group, I just added my user to that group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data my_username
```

Then, I added the folder to the group.

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www
```

Then, I gave write permissions to the www-data group.

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www
```

This worked for me without any other issue. Thanks!

Comment: You are a hero <3 . Plus One it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the absolute path and the filename with `open`:

```
$file = '/html/Projects/MD_ScrapingTool/files/filetest.txt';
```

If the file does not exist, `fopen` should create the file with `'w'` mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify that you have the permission on the folder '/html/Projects/MD_ScrapingTool/files/' and try with an absolute path.