# Can't use anything with "+" when using fopen in PHP

Tags: php, fopen

I want to read & write `.txt` file in `PHP`, I already can read the file using

```
$Readfile = fopen("file.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
```

Since I want to overwrite the file, I got suggest to use

```
$Readfile = fopen("file.txt", "r+") or exit("Unable to open file!");
```

But always end up get "Unable to open file!" I also have tried using other like `w+` but still not giving any result. here some update of my code

```
<?php
        //$Readfile = fopen("pengumuman.txt","r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
        $Readfile = file_get_contents("pengumuman.txt");
        if (isset($_POST["btnSimpan"])) {
            $pengumuman = $_POST["pengumuman"];
            fwrite($Readfile, $pengumuman);
        }
?>

<textarea class="span12" style="min-height: 200px; height: auto;" name="pengumuman">
<?php
     while(!feof($Readfile)) {
     echo fgets( $Readfile);
     }
?>
```

i tried `file_get_contents` but it give me a long loading and blank text area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing wrong with the code, since i run it in linux i need to change the permission. After deal with that everything run as it's should. Thank you. If this happen to you, just follow this link [php can't write to file in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512771/having-trouble-writing-to-a-file-with-php-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using it, you can try:

```
$Readfile = file_get_contents("file.txt");
```

The process is handled better by PHP. And later, if you wanna write to the file, you can use `file_put_contents` this way:

```
if (file_put_contents("file.txt", $Readfile . "Additional Content Here"))
  echo "File written!";
else
  echo "Error writing file!";
```

Comment: can i directly save them to .txt file too?

Comment: @AndreasChandraGaozu Yea, I have given the instructions to write the file as well. Check the updated answer?

Comment: @AndreasChandraGaozu Can you tell in simple words, what you want to do?

Comment: i wanna read the file, then update the file content through PHP, i can get anything from $Readfile = file_get_contents("file.txt");
it give me long loading & show no result of the file

Comment: @AndreasChandraGaozu How big is the `file.txt`?

Comment: it's only 676 bytes

Comment: @AndreasChandraGaozu LoL. Seriously? It looks like there's some issue with your PHP process then.

Comment: @AndreasChandraGaozu Can you please give the contents of the PHP file? I'll try doing it from my server locally and give you the updated code?

Comment: that also cross in my mind too. LOL

Comment: @AndreasChandraGaozu Did you try with a different Web Server? IIS, Apache, XAMPP, LAMP, WAMP, blah blah? Or totally a different host?

Comment: i got this above
<?php
    $Readfile = file_get_contents("pengumuman.txt");
    if (isset($_POST["btnSimpan"])) {
        $pengumuman = $_POST["pengumuman"];
        fwrite($Readfile, $pengumuman);
    }
?>
then this to show the content
<textarea class="span12" style="min-height: 200px; height: auto;" name="pengumuman">
                            <?php
                                while(!feof($Readfile)) {
                                    echo fgets( $Readfile);
                                }
                            ?>
                            </textarea>

Comment: i use apache here

Comment: @AndreasChandraGaozu Can you edit your question and put it there?

Comment: Thank you dude, nothing wrong with the code, just the permission. Since i run it in linux, i need to change the permission. After done with it, everything goes well