# Write into ubuntu folder with debian apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I have a debian 9 running apache2 with php7.
I have an ubuntu which has a shared folder (samba).
I have used fstab on debian 9 to attack the shared folder.

I can create folder with php and create file, but I cant write into the file?! What can be the problem?

```
$myfile = fopen("./mntdp/dp_handler/newfile2.txt", "w") or die("<br>Unable to open file!");
$txt = "Mickey Mouse\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Minnie Mouse\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

Warning: fopen(./mntdp/dp_handler/newfile2.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/dir.php on line 10

So the newfile2.txt is created on the ubuntu share, but I cant write in it?! Why?

I used chmod -R 777 on dp_handler the owner is the user what I use in the fstab, so the admwz user is the owner and the group is root.

I have tried so many stuff can somebody help?!

Comment: Maybe these will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512771/having-trouble-writing-to-a-file-with-php-on-ubuntu , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35711/giving-php-permission-to-write-to-files-and-folders

Comment: The problem is its two different virtual machine, so I want to write with the debian web srv into the ubuntu share.

Comment: I don't think the issue is related to being on different virtual machines. it's most likely an issue with permissions or path. Can you try using the full file path instead of relative? Use something like: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'test.txt'`

Comment: But its a network share, I cant use document root, my document root is on ./mntdp(its the share fstab conneced name) /dp_handler (its the folder what I want to write). Btw, If after file created I chmod -R 777 dp_handler than the file will be writtable and its okey. But I need to make it with php..

Comment: I have tried it now, same problem, file created but no perrmission to write into it.

Comment: When the file is created, and is not writable, what is the permission structure for that file? Like this part: `-rwxrwxrwx`. It'd be helpful if you add the result of `ls -ltra` for that file and the folder it's under.

Comment: `drwsrwsrwx+ 8 webuser  root     4096 Dec 20 12:28 ..
-rw-r--r--+ 1 admpz    www-data    0 Dec 20 12:37 newfile2.txt
-rw-r--r--+ 1 admpz    www-data    0 Dec 20 12:40 21321_20171220_124026.xml
-rw-r--r--+ 1 admpz    www-data    0 Dec 20 12:40 21321_20171220_124031.xml
-rw-r--r--+ 1 admpz    www-data    0 Dec 20 12:45 333333333_20171220_124449.xml
drwxrwsrwx+ 2 www-data www-data 4096 Dec 20 12:45 .
drwxrwsrwx+ 2 www-data www-data  4096 Dec 20 12:45 dp_handler`

Comment: I remember getting something similar once. Try doing this: 1. create file using fopen, 2. if there's an error- check if the `file_exists` and do `chmod()` from the script itself. Then try to write again. You would have to enable chmod via script, but it is doable. Try it out